# Is there a way to detect unicode chars in a nvarchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server

The input column was not implemented well enough to restrict the email chars to roman... therefore French and Spanish chars with accents have made it into the database, but are being rejected by the remote mail servers. Is there a simple SQL test?

I tried

```
where email <> try_cast(try_cast(email as varchar) as nvarchar)
```

While it seems to have worked to an extent it also seems a little aggressive in that it found more matches then non.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
where email like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9.@-_]%'
```

Comment: This will also count backticks, spaces, tabs, newlines, any control characters, plus ! " # $ % & ' / : ; < = > ? { | } ~ as Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting a size for varchar or nvarchar, so it is using the default length, which 30 I think. It's not hard to get an email address over 30 characters. Change to 'try_cast(try_cast(email as varchar(300)) as nvarchar(300))' or something like that.

However, you do realise that characters with accents, Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hindi and other characters are now valid email addresses? Not all servers have been updated to handle them, true, but that doesn't mean it isn't the actual address.

Comment: this is helpful to know but for now this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try

```
where email collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN
    <> cast(email as varchar(max)) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_BIN
```

*(You can change `varchar(max)` to be whatever the length of `email` is, though it'll work fine as `varchar(max)`, too.)*

If you don't force a Unicode-safe binary collation, then it could use whatever the database collation is, which may not work for `nchar(0x2014)` (— U+2014 EM DASH, which can be converted to `char(0x97)` by **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**), as one example.